# burp suite REST Api with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, burp

For getting BurpSuite report, I have trying to integrate my application with **BurpSuite Scanner**  by using REST API. Can anyone help me this.

Answer (score 1):

At present, Burp does not have a built-in REST API. Some users have good results with a third-party extension, [burp-rest-api](https://github.com/vmware/burp-rest-api). This includes an endpoint (/burp/scanner/issues/) that lets you fetch issues in JSON format. You can also use /burp/report to generate an HTML or XML report that includes the issues.

A built-in REST API is being developed at present.